# Select all rows that are absent in other table

Tags: mysql, left-join

There are two tables: `users1` and `users2`. They both have `name` column. I need select all users from `users1` that are absent in `users2` table.

I can only select all users and iterate them by PHP, checking every in second table.

Is there a way to do it by SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT `users1`.* FROM `users1` LEFT JOIN `users2` USING (`name`)
        WHERE `users2`.`name` IS NULL
```

For maximum performance, be sure you have an index defined on `name` in both tables.

This can also be done with a subquery (as others have pointed out), but a join will execute much faster.

Comment: You don't need an outer join.  This works just fine.  (Try it!)

Comment: ah, of course you're right. `left join` is only a shorter version of `left outer join`. It was too early in the morning I guess :) Nevertheless, using `select users1.* from ...` instead of only `*` gets rid of a ton of NULLs you don't need.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT users1.*` is clearly better than `SELECT *`.  Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to write a sub query like

```
SELECT *
FROM Users1
WHERE Username NOT IN
(SELECT Username FROm Users2)
```

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users1 where name not in (select name from users2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE name NOT IN(SELECT name FROM users2)
```

Depending on your RMDB and data in this tables, you might want to turn all names to lower case:

```
SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE LOWER(name) NOT IN(SELECT LOWER(name) FROM users2)
```